# Run time error 1004 for saving excel file (VBA required)

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if anyone knows how to use [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) to save a `.txt` file that is opened in excel?

I have tried writing a coding with a UserForm, but it is giving me errors.

I was wondering if it is possible to give user the option to save it at his/her favourite spot, and also his/her favorite name?

```
 Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox As String
 Dim QuestionToMessageBox As String
 Dim CurrentFile As String

 QuestionToMessageBox = "Do you want to save?"

YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox = MsgBox(QuestionToMessageBox, vbYesNo, "Save file")

If YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox = vbNo Then
     Unload Me 'Cancellation command
Else
CurrentFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\myfile.xls", FileFormat:=52
Workbooks.Open CurrentFile
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `MsgBox` returns a Long but you are coercing it into a String. Then you are coercing it back into a Long in order to compare it to `vbNo`, a Long constant. It would be cleaner to avoid this back-and-forth casting by declaring it as `Dim YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox As Long` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is because your file extension (xls) doesn't match your file type (OpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled).  You would need the xlsm extension.

```
Sub Command1Click()

    Dim lResp As Long
    Dim sCurrFile As String
    Dim sNewFile As String

    Const sPROMPT As String = "Do you want to save?"
    Const sFILTER As String = "*.xlsm, *.xlsm"

    lResp = MsgBox(sPROMPT, vbYesNo, "Save File")

    If lResp = vbYes Then
        sCurrFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName 'save current file name
        sNewFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(, sFILTER) 'get new file name
        If sNewFile <> "False" Then 'user didn't cancel
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sNewFile, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
            ActiveWorkbook.Close False 'close new file
            Workbooks.Open sCurrFile 'open previous text file
        End If
    Else
        Unload Me
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: hi! Thank you so much for your help! Appreciate that!

Answer (score 4):

I'm unsure why you're using Workbooks.Open after ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs. If the workbook is already open, isn't this unnecessary?

Anyway, to prompt the user for a save location try modifying the following as you require:

```
Sub DoooooooooooooooooooIt()

    Dim fd As FileDialog

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

    With fd
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Debug.Print .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: yes.. u are right.. I think i make a mistake for that line.. Anyway thank you so much for your help! Appreciate it!