# Microsoft Interop Excel SaveCopyAs with xlsx version

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

We're trying to use MS Interop Excel on Windows Server and use it through WCF (I can't really explain it in more detailed way becasue I dont really understand it fully, sorry.).

We use the method `SaveCopyAs` to save generated excel files in temp directory, then read it to byte array and send it as a reply.

However, in client application after we save it to file with `xlsx` extension and try to open it Excel gives us an warning that file is damaged, but after we manually change file name to `xls` it works all fine.

After brief research it seems that office just saves it as some kind of older file version(?). So one solution is to use the `SaveAs` method with valid parameters, but it causes us a lot of troubles so we would rather stick to `SaveCopyAs`.

*Is there any other solution to save such file in newer file format without `SaveAs` method?*

(And you probably have figured it out by now, it's the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC` exception.)

Comment: I see three possibilities: 1. Create the original Excel file in the new format already. 2. Have the client save the file with xls extension. 3. Use SaveAs() and address the problems you have with it.

Comment: Runtime error 1004 has many causes, a close match is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751622/run-time-error-1004-for-saving-excel-file-vba-required

Comment: Newer versions of Office / Excel require the file format to match the file extension. This is a security measure. So if you add an xlsx extension to a file in the old file format (xls) you get a warning - this is by design. Your other option is to not automate the Excel application in a server environment (which is anyway not supported) and work directly with the Office Open XML file format.

Comment: `SaveCopyAs` preserves the original file format. Judging by the error, the original format is `xls`. You're best option at this point is to do a `SaveAs` instead, and specify `FileFormat` to xlsx, IMHO.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, the question has been resolved, however it was mistake on our side. Person responsible for server maintenance did not check what office version (2003..) has been installed on the server what led us into such troubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the all troubles we had was our employee responsible for server maintenance who without checking said that there's office 2013 installed but in fact it is 2003.