# Error 1004 in VB while using when ActiveWorkBook.SaveAs called

Tags: vb.net, excel-2016

I have a macro file where there was piece of code in which it is trying save as `.csv` file to `.xls` file using `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` in VBA.

Actually, I have an excel file opened and now from command prompt I am passing `".csv"` file path and `"Macro.xls"` file as a parameter to Excel.exe. First it launches the .csv file and in the last piece of code in Macro.xls I found `".csv"` file is getting saved as `".xls"."c:\\1\\2\\dummy.csv"` to `"c:\\1\\2\\dummy.xls"`.

When ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs is called with the file name `"c:\\1\\2\\dummy.xls"` it throwing an error 1004. It is working fine if no excel file is opened in my machine.

This issue happens only when some excel file is already open.

```
My Code:
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
xls_file_name, FileFormat:= _
xlNormal, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", 
ReadOnlyRecommended:=False _
, CreateBackup:=False

xls_file_name:Dummy.xls
```

I am very new to VB. Could anyone suggest me to resolve this issue. This is especially in excel 2016. In excel 2010 it is working fine.

Comment: @Ron, Yeah sorry. Done.

Comment: Can you post a [Minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please? Also, have you really tried to search about [error 1004](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751622/run-time-error-1004-for-saving-excel-file-vba-required) on SO (duplicate)?

Comment: @Ayak973, Yeah tried that as well, but still I am facing the same issue only when an excel 2016 is already open. If no excel is opened I am able to save it properly. That is the reason I framed a new question and hence it is not duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution what is causing the `SaveAs` failed.

As I mentioned when an excel is opened it is not able to save, because my application was running with admin privileges and the folder in which I am writing needs the excel to be run in an admin to save in that folder. When I launch the excel in admin mode and try executing my scenario then it successfully saving.

The scenario where `SaveAs` is successful is when no excel is opened. So, in this scenario when I am launching an excel from my application, it is launching in an admin mode as my application launches with high privilege and hence the file gets saved successfully.

In brief it is all about the Access levels.

In windows 7, every excel application launches as separate process and hence the when I am launching it in windows 7 it launches in admin mode.
   ->BOOK1.xls
   ->

In windows 10, every excel application will be under a main process i.e. `EXCEL.EXE`.
For Example:

```
  EXCEL.EXE
      ->BOOk1.xls
      ->BOOK2.xls
```

As in this case "EXCEL.EXE" is launched in non admin mode, it is failing to save to folder where it is lacking admin privileges.

These are findings and want to share with you folks. Hope it helps someone facing similar kind of problem.